# Composer versioning private repositories

Tags: git, versioning, composer-php

I have several private repos on github that I use composer to load into my projects.  My composer.json file looks like this:

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url":  "git@github.com:me/my-repo.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "me/my-repo": "*"
}
...
```

How do I configure my composer.json in "me/my-repo" file so I can request certain versions of the repo?  For example, I'd like to be able to use "me/my-repo": "1.0.x" in some projects and "me/my-repo": "1.5.x-dev" in another project.

I've looked all around but have not been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use satis : https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

It will crawl your repositories and build a list of available versions for your projects.

Comment: It even builds a web view for you, it's quite a genius little tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid configuring Composer with Git or setting up your own Satis, you can try a cloud alternative.  I work for Gemfury and we will soon be introducing Composer support to our private cloud repo.  If you'd like to try it out early, here's a guide on how to get started: http://devcenter.gemfury.com/articles/php-composer-server.html